# PHP artisan suddenly doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-5

I have started to learn Laravel. Until now, everything worked perfectly. I'm following this tutorial and I'm stuck with [episode 7](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/7).

The problem is that I cannot start artisan anymore. I have tried to install tinker, and I've probably updated artisan so I ended up without artisan and tinker. I am using Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have installed everything via command line. After that I tried to run:

> php artisan --version

The following problem occurs:

> [ErrorException]
>   Declaration of App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot() should be
>   compati     ble with
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot
>   ()

This is how my file `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php` looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [
            'App\Listeners\EventListener',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);

        //
    }
}
```

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and my composer.json it looks like this:

```
"php": ">=5.5.9",
"laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
"doctrine/dbal": "^2.6@dev",
"vluzrmos/tinker": "dev-master",
"moon/artisan": "dev-master"
```

I've seen similar problems here for example:

[https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-composer-update-ends-with-an-error-suddenly](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/event-service-provider-in-package)

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/event-service-provider-in-package

but never the answer was given directly and actually I do not understand how to solve this problem? I would need direct answer because I'm newbie in Laravel. Can artisan be updated somehow easy with Linux command line so it can work again?

Comment: Laravel 5.2 hasn't even been released yet.

Comment: Like he said...Change your version to Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, the new `boot()` method doesn't take any argument. You'll have to apply some changes to the three providers.

```diff
     /**
      * Register any other events for your application.
      *
-     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
      * @return void
      */
-    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
+    public function boot()
     {
-        parent::boot($events);
+        parent::boot();

         //
     }
```

Check out this commit for the full list of changes.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/2b05ce3b054593f7622c1be6c4c6aadc1c5a54ae

Answer (score 8):

Similar to @greut answer, but if it is caused by upgrading laravel (which may be triggered if you are installing other package through `composer update` and your version for laravel is `dev-master`), there are 2 places that you need to change the parameter.

```
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider
```

In both controller, there is a method named `boot()`. Change the parameter to empty. i.e.

```
public function boot(/*original something here. empty it*/)
{
    parent::boot(/*original something here. empty it*/);
}
```

Reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/laravel-53-update-causing-error-on-forge-only/replies/189654

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem in forge while performing the upgrade to 5.3, you need to get rid of bootstrap/cache and as you mentioned artisan won’t launch because of that error so you need to do it the old way: `rm -R bootstrap/cache` and then `mkdir bootstrap/cache`. Don’t forget to apply the correct permissions of bootstrap/cache after you’re done.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking strictly from a PHP point of view, when artisan tries to start up its CLI application, and you get this error

> Declaration of App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot() should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot

You've defined a class `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`.  This class has `Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider` as an parent/ancestor (aliased as `ServiceProvider` in your class).

The boot method in **your** `Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider` has a set of arguments.  You have defined `boot` in `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`, and changed those arguments somehow (fewer arguments, different type hints, different/no defaults, etc.).

You can't do that.

Make you `boot` compatible with the parent class, and you'l fix your problem.

(This, however, might not fix all your problems, as the comments make it sound like you're using an unreleased version of Laravel that may differ from what's in a tutorial)

Comment: Alan Strom - where can I found Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider so I know it is exactly "there" problem and not in some other file?

I acutally did not do anything..I haven't defined any boot before, and I'm not sure now how could I make my "boot compatible with the parent class"? I think I should be using Laravel 5.1

Comment: @DarioBB look for the string `"function boot"` in a file in the filesystem under a path at `Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers\EventServiceProvider.php` or something very similar to that. Because of PSR4, you can know the filesystem path because it will match the namespace. It sounds like `EventServiceProvider::boot()` is an interface-declared function, and you are missing arguments that are declared there.